# Modifying multiple places in file in one iteration Python

Tags: python, regex, text-files

I am attempting to modify a file, wherein I wish to replace some brackets with added parameters. However, using `re.search` stops at first success and even `re.findall` does not help.

```
def Modify_Brackets(file_name):
    input=open(file_name,"r")
    output = open("help.txt", "w+")
    for line in input:
        text = input.read()
        matches = re.findall(r'(rule).*([0-9]+).*:.*(\[.*\])(\s*)\-\-(\s*)(\[.*\])(\s*)\-\>(\s*)(\[.*])', text)
        for m in matches:
            Brackets= m[5][1:-1]
            ModifiedBrackets = re.sub(r'\)',',changed)',Brackets)
            newline = text.replace(m[5], ModifiedBrackets)
            output.write(newline)
        else:
            output.write(text + "")
```

**Input :**

```
<some text>
rule abc1 :  [some text]
  --[ f(a,b), g(x,y)    ]->
          [some text]
<some text>
<some text>
rule abc2 :  [some text]
  --[ f(x,b), g(a,y)    ]->
         [some text]
```

**Present output :**

```
<some text>
rule abc1 :  [some text]
  --[ f(a,b,changed), g(x,y,changed)    ]->
          [some text]
<some text>
<some text>
rule abc2 :  [some text]
  --[ f(x,b), g(a,y)    ]->
         [some text]
```

**Expected output :**

```
<some text>
rule abc1 :  [some text]
  --[ f(a,b,changed), g(x,y,changed)    ]->
          [some text]
<some text>
<some text>
rule abc2 :  [some text]
  --[ f(x,b,changed), g(a,y,changed)    ]->
         [some text]
```

As you can see, it works well for the first rule only and stops after that. I want this change over all the rules present in the file.

Comment: I believe your for loop isn't set up correctly. Checkout how to read a file in line by line here http://stackabuse.com/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/

Comment: The reading part is working fine. In fact, I am able to extract all the lines that match the search criteria. The problem is that it stops at first success. So I am either able to print replaced text file lines that match the criteria or complete file with only first replacement.

Comment: Can you put a console.log in the for loop and see how many times it's iterating?